# Cannot rotate image about center css

Tags: html, css

So I want to rotate an icon in place using css.

I've tried this

```
.rotate-icon-gif {
    -webkit-animation-name: spin;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 4000ms;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -moz-animation-name: spin;
    -moz-animation-duration: 4000ms;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -ms-animation-name: spin;
    -ms-animation-duration: 4000ms;
    -ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -ms-animation-timing-function: linear;

    animation-name: spin;
    animation-duration: 4000ms;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@-ms-keyframes spin {
    from { 
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg); 
    }
    to { -ms-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@-moz-keyframes spin {
    from { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    from { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
            -webkit-transform-origin: 30px 22px;

     }
    to { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); 
            -webkit-transform-origin: 30px 22px;

    }
}
@keyframes spin {
    from {
        transform:rotate(0deg);
        transform-origin: 55% 50%;
    }
    to {
        transform:rotate(360deg);
        transform-origin: 55% 50%;
    }
}
```

But it won't rotate in place - it rotates about some other center.

[image]
[image]

I've looked at the dimensions of the div that has this -

It's 60 x 30, with 15 padding on top. Hence, I've tried to make the transform-origin on 30px and 22px offsets.

It's still not working - how should I go about fixing this?

Comment: you mean it's incorrect like this? http://jsfiddle.net/CBLxu/  If you could create a more correct demo that would be great

Answer (score 2):

There are two methods of achieving this. Firstly, you can edit the image so the center lies directly on the axis of rotation.

### First Method

Using cropped image. (No CSS added, deleted obsolete `transition-origin`)

See **snippet:**

```css
.rotate-icon-gif {
    -webkit-animation-name: spin;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 4000ms;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -moz-animation-name: spin;
    -moz-animation-duration: 4000ms;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -ms-animation-name: spin;
    -ms-animation-duration: 4000ms;
    -ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -ms-animation-timing-function: linear;

    animation-name: spin;
    animation-duration: 4000ms;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@-ms-keyframes spin {
    from { 
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg); 
    }
    to { -ms-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@-moz-keyframes spin {
    from { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    from { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);

     }
    to { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); 

    }
}
@keyframes spin {
    from {
        transform:rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
        transform:rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/tPLLoew.png" class="rotate-icon-gif">
```

### Second Method

You can use `transform-origin: x y;` Here, you need to find the x and y coordinates of the axis using **Paint** or **Photoshop** like this: (You need to find the coordinates of intersection of black line)

[image]

See **snippet :**

```css
.rotate-icon-gif {
  -webkit-animation-name: spin;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -moz-animation-name: spin;
  -moz-animation-duration: 4s;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -ms-animation-name: spin;
  -ms-animation-duration: 4s;
  -ms-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -ms-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-name: spin;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}
@-ms-keyframes spin {
  from {
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform-origin: 42px 35px;
  }
  to {
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform-origin: 42px 35px;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes spin {
  from {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform-origin: 42px 35px;
  }
  to {
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform-origin: 42px 35px;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 42px 35px;
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 42px 35px;
  }
}
@keyframes spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform-origin: 42px 35px;
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform-origin: 42px 35px;
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZ2CV.png" class="rotate-icon-gif">
```

**NOTE** - From my other answer : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27744153/2511146)

Comment: Second such question today for you in quick succession, eh! :) Have to +1 this, as the earlier one!